# Esperar variável ser definida para "abrir sinaleiro"

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu tenho a variável `x` que passa por processos para ser realmente definida e isso demora um pouco, e para mexer no resto da aplicação eu preciso que ela esteja definida, ou seja eu preciso esperar ela ser definida se nao o projeto trava..

Como esperar a variável ser definida para liberar as outras coisas.. Eu pensei em um setinterval infinito mas seria gambiarra, há algo mais robusto?

Answer (score 0):

```
// quero que perceba que é só um exemplo. Adapte para o seu código

var variavel = 0;
setaValorEmX(variavel, function(erro, resultado){

    //verifica se retornou erro da funcao assincrona
    if(erro){
        throw erro;
    }

    if (resultado) {
        console.log(resultado)
        //faz o seu codigo
    };


});


function setaValorEmX(x, callback){
    //coloque o codigo que seta o valor em x
    x = 1;

    //
    callback(null, x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sim, você pode usar [jQuery Deferred](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/):

```js
var defer = $.Deferred();
var x = defer.promise();
x.then(function(value){
  alert(value);
});
defer.resolve('pronto');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```